# Display video in full screen inside table view cell

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have one scrollview inside which i have displayed tableview. I have custom cell and i want to display video on click on that. It's working nicely but when i am clicking on full screen button my application gets crashed. So how can i resolve this issue.. 
My code to display video is given below.

```
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer= [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake([cordinate.x integerValue], [cordinate.y integerValue], [cordinate.width integerValue], [cordinate.height integerValue]);
    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
    [cell addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
```

Please help me to solve this..

Comment: First question: why you have take tableview inside scrollview? second question : can you post your crash log?

Comment: Check out this link.. You have to manage the and track `MPMoviePlayerStates` 

Link - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification

Comment: i want the paging functionality that's why i have taken scrollview.. my error log   [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
2012-11-30 12:49:40.145 MagazineApp[5045:14003] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
2012-11-30 12:49:40.181 MagazineApp[5045:14003] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
2012-11-30 12:49:40.182 MagazineApp[5045:14003] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay Autoplay: _streamLikelyToKeepUp: 0 -> 1
2012-11-30 12:49:43.899 MagazineApp[5045:14003] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause

Comment: why you add this line [addSubview:moviePlayer]; again

Answer (score 0):

Add this line and then check it work or not:

```
moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.frame;
```

and remove this line `[addSubview:moviePlayer];`